# Lync server clientless audio video

Tags: silverlight, lync

I wish to make a web based IM system for a website with Lync server, it must have audio and video capabilities though. Is this possible? I understand you cannot do it with the UCWA Web API for Lync, but can you use Silverlight and the Lync SDK to achieve this? Or must all computers that use audio video have the lync client installed?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to do this is for all computers to have the Lync client installed.

UCWA currently only does IM and Presence. Voice and Video IS coming to UCWA and is expected this year. (announced at Lync Conference 2014 keynote)

The Silverlight controls require Lync on the machine - they won't work without it.